# How to fix matching end-tag error within JavaScript on Blogger?

Tags: javascript, xml, blogger

I'm using this code to have an alphabetical unordered list with JavaScript in Blogger. This works in CodePen and JSFiddle but when I use it in Blogger, upon saving I get this error: `Error parsing XML, line 1007, column 3: The element type "li" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "".`. It's referring to this line: `$this.before('<li class="splitter">' + firstLetter);`. How to go about fixing this?

```js
var list = $('ul'),
    items = $('li', list);

// sort the list
var sortedItems = items.get().sort(function(a, b) {
  var aText = $.trim($(a).text().toUpperCase()),
      bText = $.trim($(b).text().toUpperCase());
  
   return aText.localeCompare(bText);
});

list.append(sortedItems); 

// create the titles
var lastLetter = '';
list.find('li').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this),
      text = $.trim($this.text()),
      firstLetter = text[0];

  if (firstLetter != lastLetter) {
    $this.before('<li class="splitter">' + firstLetter);
    lastLetter = firstLetter;
  }
});
```

```css
.splitter {
  border-top: 1px solid;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  list-style: none;
  padding-top: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#/"> john-doe/</a></li>
  <li><a href="#/"> jane-doe/</a></li>
  <li><a href="#/"> glen-doe/</a></li>
  <li><a href="#/"> daniel-doe/</a></li>
  <li><a href="#/"> matthew-doe/</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap javascript code with the [CDATA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA) tag to prevent Blogger XML parser from interpret it.

```
//<![CDATA[

var list = $('ul'),
    items = $('li', list);

// sort the list
var sortedItems = items.get().sort(function(a, b) {
  var aText = $.trim($(a).text().toUpperCase()),
      bText = $.trim($(b).text().toUpperCase());

   return aText.localeCompare(bText);
});

list.append(sortedItems); 

// create the titles
var lastLetter = '';
list.find('li').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this),
      text = $.trim($this.text()),
      firstLetter = text[0];

  if (firstLetter != lastLetter) {
    $this.before('<li class="splitter">' + firstLetter);
    lastLetter = firstLetter;
  }
});

//]]>
```

Comment: This does help with the error so that's great. However, the intended effect still isn't applied. I only get a bulleted list. Either this script just cannot work in blogger or I'm doing something wrong. Do you think you can try replicating this on a test blog?

Comment: What do you want to do after sorting! show me the desired result.